# problem with table format while downloading pdf in iTextSharp in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext

I am using iTextsharp 5.5 to download my data as pdf in which I worked with the following [Link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-a-pdf-file-and-download-using-Asp-Net-mvc/) example, below is the pdf which is downloaded

[image]

In the above Image (#800000) background represent my headers, as you can see my image above the headers are not aligned properly

below is my code for the same

```
public FileResult DownloadInventoryDumpReportPdf(int AccountId, int UserId, int ItemStatusId)
{
    MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();
    StringBuilder status = new StringBuilder("");
    DateTime dTime = DateTime.Now;

    DocPro.RMS.BusinessLayer.Reports.IInventoryDumpReport a = (DocPro.RMS.BusinessLayer.Reports.IInventoryDumpReport)DALFinder.GetInstance(typeof(DocPro.RMS.BusinessLayer.Reports.IInventoryDumpReport));
    var result = a.Get(AccountId, UserId, ItemStatusId);

    BusinessLayer.IMaster.IRefFieldSetting b = (BusinessLayer.IMaster.IRefFieldSetting)DALFinder.GetInstance(typeof(BusinessLayer.IMaster.IRefFieldSetting));
    var headers = b.GetRefField(UserId);

    //file name to be created   
    string strPDFFileName = string.Format("SamplePdf" + dTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "-" + ".pdf");
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
    //Create PDF Table with 5 columns  
    PdfPTable tableLayout = new PdfPTable(21);
    doc.SetMargins(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f);
    //Create PDF Table  

    //file will created in this path  
    string strAttachment = Server.MapPath("~/Downloadss/" + strPDFFileName);


    PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, workStream).CloseStream = false;
    doc.Open();

    //Add Content to PDF   
    doc.Add(AddContentToPDF(tableLayout, headers, result));

    // Closing the document  
    doc.Close();

    byte[] byteInfo = workStream.ToArray();
    workStream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
    workStream.Position = 0;


    return File(workStream, "application/pdf", strPDFFileName);

}

protected PdfPTable AddContentToPDF(PdfPTable tableLayout, BusinessEntities.Master.REFField header, List<BusinessEntities.Reports.InventoryDumpReport> result)
{
    tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Creating Pdf using ItextSharp", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(0, 0, 0))))
    {
        Colspan = 12,
        Border = 0,
        PaddingBottom = 5,
        HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER
    });

    ////Add header  
    AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "SrNo");
    AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Item Code");
    AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Item Description");
    AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Alternate Code");
    AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Object Name");

    AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Location Code");
    AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Container Code");
    AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Shipper Code");
    AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Status");
    AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "New Status DateTime");

    AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Expiry Date");
    AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Created By");
    AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Created Date");
    AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Modified By");
    AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Modified Date");

    AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, header.displayName01);
    AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, header.displayName02);
    AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, header.displayName03);
    AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, header.displayName04);
    AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, header.displayName05);
    AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, header.displayName06);

    ////Add body  
    var currentIndex = 1;
    foreach (var d in result)
    {
        var ItemStatusDateTime = d.ItemStatusDateTime == null ? "" : d.ItemStatusDateTime;
        var ExpiryDate = d.ExpiryDate == null ? "" : d.ExpiryDate;
        var CreatedDate = d.CreatedDate == null ? "" : d.CreatedDate;
        var ModifiedDate = d.ModifiedDate == null ? "" : d.ModifiedDate;

        AddCellToBody(tableLayout, currentIndex.ToString());
        AddCellToBody(tableLayout, d.ItemCode);
        AddCellToBody(tableLayout, d.ItemDescription);
        AddCellToBody(tableLayout, d.AlternateCode);
        AddCellToBody(tableLayout, d.ObjectName);

        AddCellToBody(tableLayout, d.LocationCode);
        AddCellToBody(tableLayout, d.ContainerItemCode);
        AddCellToBody(tableLayout, d.ShipperCode);
        AddCellToBody(tableLayout, d.Status);
        AddCellToBody(tableLayout, ItemStatusDateTime);

        AddCellToBody(tableLayout, ExpiryDate);
        AddCellToBody(tableLayout, d.CreatedByUserName);
        AddCellToBody(tableLayout, CreatedDate);
        AddCellToBody(tableLayout, d.ModifiedByUserName);
        AddCellToBody(tableLayout, ModifiedDate);

        AddCellToBody(tableLayout, d.Ref01);
        AddCellToBody(tableLayout, d.Ref02);
        AddCellToBody(tableLayout, d.Ref03);
        AddCellToBody(tableLayout, d.Ref04);
        AddCellToBody(tableLayout, d.Ref05);
        AddCellToBody(tableLayout, d.Ref06);
        currentIndex++;
    }
    return tableLayout;
}

private static void AddCellToHeader(PdfPTable tableLayout, string cellText)
{

    tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellText, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK)))
    {
        HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
        Padding = 5,
        BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(128, 0, 0)
    });
}

// Method to add single cell to the body  
private static void AddCellToBody(PdfPTable tableLayout, string cellText)
{
    tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellText, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 8, 1, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK)))
    {
        HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
        Padding = 5,
        BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(255, 255, 255)
    });
}
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: `//Create PDF Table with 5 columns` followed by
    `PdfPTable tableLayout = new PdfPTable(21);` does not really match. And your result looks like you Indeed have a `new PdfPTable(5)` there...

Answer (score 2):

I think iText did exactly what you asked for, no? What result do you expect? I suppose something like this:

[image: Expected result?]

Just add empty cells where necessary, 4 empty cells on each iteration in your case.